# AWS/Sam CodeURI and Handler specification issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I have been having all kinds of problems using/specifying CodeUri and Handler specifications consistently.

It is my understanding that the way it supposed to work is that if you have a source tree of
`<project-dir>/src/api/...` and `<project-dir>/src/lib/...`
etc., you should be able to specify  `CodeUri: src/` and then the handlers can be specified as `Handler: api....app.lambda_handler` alleviating the need to prefix everything with `src`.  This then holds true for any files we access from within a handler -- i.e., the path(s) to a template file like `"./src/lib/categories/all.json"` should be able to be referenced as `"./lib/categories/all.json"`

I have had it happen that the first function defined can use `CodeUri: src/` but the remaining functions won't work unless `CodeUri:` is removed and then the handlers are specified as `Handler: src.api...app.lambda_handler`. (It does not matter if you specify '.' or '/' as the delimiter in the `Handler` syntax.)

Furthermore, for the instance where the first function was able to use `CodeUri: src/`  we found that when deployed into a different AWS/Sam stack/container by my colleague, it no longer accepted the `CodeUri` specification and we had to revert everything to use the `Handler: src.api...app.lambda_handler` form to get it to work across deployment containers.

So, my questions is "What am I missing regarding using `CodeUri` and `Handler` specifications, or my `template.yaml` in general, to make this more usable and consistent?.  Any help would be appreciated.